# Good text on introduction to circuit complexity

Tags: circuit-complexity

I would like to ask suggestions for good texts which introduce circuit complexity. Any pointers to recent advances and open problems in this field would also be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To start off, there is of course Arora and Barak's book [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/). From there, parts 3 and 4 of Jukna's book [Boolean Function Complexity: Advances and Frontiers](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/boolean/) make excellent reading material. Also, Ryan Williams teaches a [nice course on circuit complexity](http://www.stanford.edu/~rrwill/cs354.html) whose course notes might hopefully be put up online :)

Comment: Eventually, eventually :)

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the ones suggested by Arnab, I would also recommend the following book:

> Introduction to Circuit Complexity: A Uniform Approach by Heribert Vollmer

Answer (score 1):

[Models of Computation](http://cs.brown.edu/~jes/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation.pdf) by John E Savage (more info/detail/reviews on [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201895390)). its largely more of an undergraduate textbook but is notable for its circuit-centric point of view. includes many advanced topics/proofs, and its free online, and is very well hyperlinked (TOC, refs, index, etc).